# What happens when we measure the particle *before* the double slit?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality, wavefunction-collapse

Like the titles states, if we measure the particle before the double slit, like right after it gets shot out, do we see an interference pattern or clump pattern on the screen after the slits?

Comment: A measurement of the particle's position before the double slit will affect its momentum. The most likely outcome is that the particle will completely miss both slits, and you won't see anything at all on the screen.

Comment: Ignoring that issue, you'd see an  pattern, because you'd get a superposition after the particle interacts with the two slits.

Comment: You basically do this already, since the position of the particle at time of emission is confined to within the emitter.

Comment: I think the key issue is that pop science presents quantum particles as either "measured" and hence totally normal, or "unmeasured", and hence totally weird. There's not such a sharp distinction between the two. For example, a particle that's just been subjected to a position measurement, and hence has definite position, very quickly evolves into a particle with indefinite position.

Comment: So gravitaunt's answer is correct? If you measure the particle let's say right after it gets shot out, the pattern on the other side of the double slits will be clumps not interference?

Answer (score 1):

No, if you measure the particle after the slit you won't have an interference pattern. If you know from which slit it passed through, then there won't be any interference effects.

On the other hand, if you don't make any measurements in the middle, then you have interference and you are forced to say the particle went through both slits.

Comment: Ok, well we wouldn't be measuring which slit the particles goes through we'd just be measuring it before it went through the slits. Anyway i guess my question was intended to determine whether measurement collapses a wavefunction indefinitely or just "reoriginates the wave at the location of measurement. (Ex. WWWPWWWP vs. WWWPPP). What you're saying implies it's the latter.

Comment: Ok so if you measure it right after it get shots out and then let it travel for a while and go through the double slits you'll get an interference pattern? Sorry but i've asked this question like 10 different times and get a different answer each time.